# how to see the array in the custom modules function hook_entity_info() in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, entity, drupal-modules, associative-array

How to see the entire array that is returned by the function mymodule_entity_info() in the .module file in a custom module folder in drupal/sites/all/module/mymodule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 7 there is a function called debug() that you can pass an array to. See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/debug/7